# Visual Studio 2005 to send notification on build completion

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2005

OS: Windows 7
Visual Studio 2005 SP1 + Visual Assist X 1830

Looks like there's no way to do this for VS2005. I know in Windows control panel > Sound settings, we can set VS2008/2010 Build Finishes/Success/Error sounds. However, I was wondering if we can set any type of notifications? Like making the VS icon on taskbar flashing (similar to getting new message in MSN Messenger). Is that possible?